# Accessing Photos app for sharing / editing

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am making a photo app that takes pictures and saves to the photo library. I would like the user to be able to go to the library of photos for the purpose of sharing / editing / deleting photos just like in the actual camera app. To clarify I don't want to access the image picker to select an image then load it back into my app. I want to open the actual photos app from within my app so the user can do stuff to them there using the existing inbuilt photos app functionality. Is this possible? It seems to work in the default Apple camera app but I haven't seen it anywhere else. I can't seem to find anything about this because when I google it I keep getting stuff about the image picker.

Right now the best I have is as follows but you leave my app

```
UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string:"photos-redirect://")!)
```

Comment: If you letting user to do stuff from native photos app, then what is the use of your photo app?

Comment: Hi it's an AR app takes photos with the AR then I just want to save to photo library and let the user do what he wants with the photos. To make it easier I'd like to just have a shortcut to photo lib

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the

> UIActivityViewController

The system provides several standard services, such as copying items to the pasteboard, posting content to social media sites, sending items via email or SMS, and more. Apps can also define custom services.

```
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiactivityviewcontroller
```

Answer (score -1):

Create a new swift file, such as Camera.swift and copy this code into it.

Note: You must add the privacy permission to your info.plist.

[image]

```
import Foundation
import MobileCoreServices
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class Camera {
    var delegate: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate & UINavigationControllerDelegate

    init(source: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate & UINavigationControllerDelegate) {
        delegate = source
    }

    func PresentPhotoInput(target: UIViewController, canEdit: Bool = false) {

        let picker = UIAlertController(title: "Select Photo Source", message: "Would you like to take a new photo or add one from your photo library?", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.actionSheet)

        picker.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { (action) in
            self.PresentMultyCamera(target: target, canEdit: canEdit)
        }))

        picker.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Photo Library", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { (action) in
            self.PresentPhotoLibrary(target: target, canEdit: canEdit)
        }))

        picker.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.destructive, handler: { (action) in
            // foo
        }))

        target.present(picker, animated: true)

    }

    func PresentPhotoLibrary(target: UIViewController, canEdit: Bool) {
        if !UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary) && !UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.savedPhotosAlbum) {
            return
        }

        let type = kUTTypeImage as String
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()

        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.photoLibrary) {
            imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary

            if let availableTypes = UIImagePickerController.availableMediaTypes(for: .photoLibrary) {
                if (availableTypes as NSArray).contains(type) {
                    /* Set up defaults */
                    imagePicker.mediaTypes = [type]
                    imagePicker.allowsEditing = canEdit
                }
            }
        } else if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.savedPhotosAlbum) {
            imagePicker.sourceType = .savedPhotosAlbum

            if let availableTypes = UIImagePickerController.availableMediaTypes(for: .savedPhotosAlbum) {
                if (availableTypes as NSArray).contains(type) {
                    imagePicker.mediaTypes = [type]
                }
            }
        } else {
            return
        }

        imagePicker.allowsEditing = canEdit
        imagePicker.delegate = delegate
        target.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil) // presents the imagepicker to the user

        return
    }

    func PresentMultyCamera(target: UIViewController, canEdit: Bool) {
        if !UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera) {
            return
        }

        let type1 = kUTTypeImage as String
        //let type2 = kUTTypeMovie as String

        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()

        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera) {
            if let availableTypes = UIImagePickerController.availableMediaTypes(for: .camera) {
                if (availableTypes as NSArray).contains(type1) {
                    imagePicker.mediaTypes = [type1/*, type2*/]
                    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera
                    imagePicker.showsCameraControls = true
                }
            }
            if UIImagePickerController.isCameraDeviceAvailable(.rear) {
                imagePicker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDevice.rear
            } else if UIImagePickerController.isCameraDeviceAvailable(.front) {
                imagePicker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDevice.front
            }
        } else {
            // show alert, no camera available
            return
        }

        imagePicker.allowsEditing = canEdit
        imagePicker.showsCameraControls = true
        imagePicker.delegate = delegate
        target.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil) // presents the imagepicker to the user
    }

    func PresentPhotoCamera(target: UIViewController, canEdit: Bool) {
        if !UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera) {
            return
        }

        let type1 = kUTTypeImage as String

        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()

        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera) {
            if let availableTypes = UIImagePickerController.availableMediaTypes(for: .camera) {
                if (availableTypes as NSArray).contains(type1) {
                    imagePicker.mediaTypes = [type1]
                    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera
                }
            }
            if UIImagePickerController.isCameraDeviceAvailable(.rear) {
                imagePicker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDevice.rear
            } else if UIImagePickerController.isCameraDeviceAvailable(.front) {
                imagePicker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDevice.front
            }
        } else {
            // show alert, no camera available
            return
        }

        imagePicker.allowsEditing = canEdit
        imagePicker.showsCameraControls = true
        imagePicker.delegate = delegate
        App.shared.isAuthenticating = true
        target.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil) // presents the imagepicker to the user
    }

    // Video Camera
    func PresentVideoCamera(target: UIViewController, canEdit: Bool) {
        if !UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera) {
            return
        }

        let type1 = kUTTypeMovie as String

        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()

        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera) {
            if let availableTypes = UIImagePickerController.availableMediaTypes(for: .camera) {
                if (availableTypes as NSArray).contains(type1) {
                    imagePicker.mediaTypes = [type1]
                    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera
                    imagePicker.videoMaximumDuration = 15.0
                }
            }
            if UIImagePickerController.isCameraDeviceAvailable(.rear) {
                imagePicker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDevice.rear
            } else if UIImagePickerController.isCameraDeviceAvailable(.front) {
                imagePicker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDevice.front
            }
        } else {
            // show alert, no camera available
            return
        }

        imagePicker.allowsEditing = canEdit
        imagePicker.showsCameraControls = true
        imagePicker.delegate = delegate
        target.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil) // presents the imagepicker to the user
    }

    // video library
    func PresentVideoLibrary(target: UIViewController, canEdit: Bool) {
        if !UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary) && !UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.savedPhotosAlbum) {
            return
        }

        let type = kUTTypeMovie as String
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()

        imagePicker.videoMaximumDuration = 15.0

        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.photoLibrary) {
            imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary

            if let availableTypes = UIImagePickerController.availableMediaTypes(for: .photoLibrary) {
                if (availableTypes as NSArray).contains(type) {
                    /* Set up defaults */
                    imagePicker.mediaTypes = [type]
                    imagePicker.allowsEditing = canEdit
                }
            }
        } else if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.savedPhotosAlbum) {
            imagePicker.sourceType = .savedPhotosAlbum

            if let availableTypes = UIImagePickerController.availableMediaTypes(for: .savedPhotosAlbum) {
                if (availableTypes as NSArray).contains(type) {
                    imagePicker.mediaTypes = [type]
                }
            }
        } else {
            return
        }

        imagePicker.allowsEditing = canEdit
        imagePicker.delegate = delegate
        target.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil) // presents the imagepicker to the user

        return
    }
}
```

Now you can use this class a shortcut for accessing the photo library. An example is provided below.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class Example: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func some_action() {
        let camera = Camera(source: self)

        camera.PresentPhotoInput(target: self)

        //camera.PresentPhotoCamera(target: self, canEdit: false)

    }

    // MARK: - Image Picker Delegate Function

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String: Any]) {


        if picker.sourceType == .photoLibrary {

            if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage {
                // do something
            } else if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
                // do something
            }

            picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else if picker.sourceType == .camera {

            // do something

            picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

}
```

Hope this helps!